# Which is the difference between $doc.getElementById("id") and document.getElementById("id") in JSNI

Tags: dom, gwt, jsni

I'm working in a native function inside a GWT application and I've tried this two methods: document.getElementById("id") returns null but $doc.getElementById() returns a valid element.
Which is the difference (conceptually) between this methods?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The code of your GWT app runs in a (hidden) iframe, so `document` references that iframe's document (and `window` the iframe's browsing context). GWT thus initializes the variables `$doc` and `$wnd` to let you easily reference the document and browsing context (*window*) of the "host page" that loads the GWT app.

Note that linkers decide how the compiled code is loaded, the default one (`std`) and the newer `xsiframe` use iframes, whereas the deprecated `xs` loads your code in the same browsing context (so `$doc == document` and `$wnd == window`)

Answer (score 2):

From the [GWT JSNI page](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html):

> Note that the code did not reference the JavaScript window object directly inside the method. When accessing the browser's window and document objects from JSNI, you must reference them as $wnd and $doc, respectively. Your compiled script runs in a nested frame, and $wnd and $doc are automatically initialized to correctly refer to the host page's window and document.