# To Preview the content in textarea

Tags: java, gwt

I am getting the following error while previewing the content in a IE browser. I do not understand why this error is occuring. The stack of error is as follows:

> 00:37:03.281 [ERROR] Uncaught exception escaped
>   java.lang.AssertionError: Tried to remove unknown handler: com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ListenerWrapper$WrappedClickListener@54b245 from Event type    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager$HandlerRegistry.removeHandler(HandlerManager.java:98)     at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager$HandlerRegistry.access$7(HandlerManager.java:91)  at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.doRemove(HandlerManager.java:273)     at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.access$1(HandlerManager.java:271)     at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager$2.execute(HandlerManager.java:289)    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.handleQueuedAddsAndRemoves(HandlerManager.java:298)   at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:183)    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:52)   at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)  at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:100)     at com.capgent.cpt.client.ImageRollover.onBrowserEvent(ImageRollover.java:250)  at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1307)  at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1263)  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor218.invoke(Unknown Source)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:264)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)   at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:188)   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor164.invoke(Unknown Source)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessages(BrowserChannel.java:1668)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:401)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

The code for previewing the content is as follows:

```
private static native void previewContent() /*-{
   top.consoleRef = window.open("","previewTemplate","");
   top.consoleRef.document.writeln(
      '<html><head><title>Template Preview</title></head>'
      +'<body>'
      + value
      +'</body></html>'
   )
   top.consoleRef.document.close()
}-*/;
```

Where `value` is the content to preview.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is your error, but you have to use `$wnd` instead of `window` in your JSNI methods.

From [GWT JSNI page:](http://code.google.com/intl/de-AT/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html)

> Note that the code did not reference the JavaScript window object
>   directly inside the method. When accessing the browser's window and
>   document objects from JSNI, you must reference them as $wnd and $doc,
>   respectively. Your compiled script runs in a nested frame, and $wnd
>   and $doc are automatically initialized to correctly refer to the host
>   page's window and document.

Also see this question: [Which is the difference between $doc.getElementById(“id”) and document.getElementById(“id”) in JSNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308911/which-is-the-difference-between-doc-getelementbyidid-and-document-getelemen)